# Vuex: getter to dispatch action if no data is in the state

Tags: vuex

I use vuex for my state as well as fetching data and display it in my application.
But I wonder if I'm doing it right. At the moment I dispatch an `fetchDataAsync` action from the component `mounted` hook, and I have an getter to display my data. Below is a code example of how I do it currently.

I wonder if it's necessary. What I really want is a getter, that looks at the state, checks if the data is already there and if the data is not there it is able to dispatch an action to fetch the missing data.

The API of vuex does not allow it so I need to put more logic into my components. E.g. if the data is depended of a prop I need a watcher that looks at the prop and dispatches the `fetchDataAsync`  action.
For me it just feels wrong and I wonder if there is a better way.

```js
let store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    posts: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    addPost(state, post) {
      Vue.set(state.posts, post.id, post);
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchPostAsync({ commit }, parameter) {
      setTimeout(
        () =>
          commit("addPost", { id: parameter, message: "got loaded asynchronous" }),
        1000
      );
    }
  },
  getters: {
    // is it somehow possible to detect: ob boy, I don't have this id,
    // I'd better dispatch an action trying to fetch it...?
    getPostById: (state) => (id) => state.posts[id]
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  template : "<div>{{ postToDisplay ? postToDisplay.message : 'loading...' }} </div>",
  data() {
    return {
      parameter: "a"
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapGetters(["getPostById"]),
    postToDisplay() {
      return this.getPostById(this.parameter);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...Vuex.mapActions(["fetchPostAsync"])
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchPostAsync(this.parameter);
  }
});
```

I also created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/christianmurschall/pen/XWKReQG)

Comment: IMO the getter should never attempt to do anything that is not completed synchronously, since their declared purpose is filtering/formatting existing data. Dispatching actions from inside a getter adds an asynchronous side-effect that is impossible to predict without examining the getter's code.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think the solution you suggested (adding a watcher that dispatches `fetchPostAsync` if the post is not found) is the best one. As another commenter stated, getters should not have side effects.

Comment: Thank you! That’s what I feared. It’s completely okay that getters should be synchronous filter/mappers without side effects. 
Why I dislike my solution ist that it puts state management concerned logic out of the actual state management system into my component...